# Can we burninate [tracking]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

The [tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tracking) tag has the following description:

> DO NOT USE, since is considered too generic. Consider using a more specific tag such as [video-tracking] or [bug-tracking] instead.

In addition to the two topics mentioned in the tag description, here are some examples of topics of questions tagged with this tag:

- Vehicle tracking
- Phone monitoring
- Website traffic tracking

That being said, this is clearly ambiguous - those are five separate possible meanings, and I haven't even listed all of the possible uses.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

On the plus side, technically, all of these meanings are on-topic, but I don't think that that's a good reason to keep the tag.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

The tag is adding little meaning to the post other than it's asking how to track *something* (which could be just about anything).

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

This tag clearly does not mean the same thing in all common contexts.

Can we burninate this?

Comment: Is it possible to separate the tags? `phone-tracking`, `website-tracking`, etc? Is it going to be useful?

Comment: Love that the description is "DO NOT USE", and yet it's getting used at least once a day; shows how little people pay attention to the tags they use other than to try and get more visibility from the poor users that go to read their question.

Comment: So the question is not about writing a SEDE request to track the usage of tag with “DO NOT USE" guidance?

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah, that would at least be unambiguous.

Comment: @Larnu Yeah, "DO NOT USE" tag usage guidance isn't very effective because the majority of users don't read tag usage guidance. Better to remove it entirely IMHO.

Comment: I don't disagree about hi ust removing a "DO NOT USE", but unfortunately my comment extends to more than just those types of tags (such as users that tag `sql-server` because they are using SQL on a Server, and not because they are using Microsoft SQL Server; as the tag states).

Comment: @Larnu the `java` tag starts with "not to be confused with JavaScript, JScript or JS" and the JavaScript tag also says "not to be confused with Java". That doesn't stop people from either mistaking one for the other or just assuming both are the same at least once a day or so.

Comment: That would be encompassed in my point, @VLAZ .

Comment: @Larnu I know. Just adding more examples.

Comment: Some kind of obsolete flag? So we don't have to read the guidance to distinguish the bad tag from the one that apply only in specific context. So maintance and usage of said tag can be done by editing a checking/unchecking the tag.

Comment: If it was a SEDE query you were after, then perhaps [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1185381/number-of-questions-on-do-not-use-tags#messages)?

Comment: I realize that tradition demands that a question like this should have a weak pun in the title, but this one is really quite misleading. Can I suggest something simpler like *"send [tag:tracking] packing?"*

Comment: @xdtTransform: no it's more than just counting the raw count, because sometimes 'DO NOT USE' tags get deleted later (and blacklisted). So 60+20-5 tells a slightly different story to 60+15. Another aspect of the question would be tracking tags getting blacklisted. (Is there a SEDE query for blacklisted tags?)

Comment: @Larnu I am not even *remotely* surprised that people don't read that text, because it barely shows up in the first place. It won't persist after adding the tag unless you go out of your way to check it again, and there's no built-in motivation to do so.